# How would I return the names of players in each Entry using Prisma?

Tags: node.js, orm, prisma

I have a database of fantasy sports entries. Each entry is a many-to-many relationship with players in the league. I want to return all entries with the first name and last name of the players related to that entry.

I've attempted a number of iterations of select and include but can only seem to return players as a series of [Object] and can't access the properties inside.

The latest syntax I'm using is below:

```
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';

const prisma = new PrismaClient();

const getPlayerdata = async () => {
    // await prisma.player.deleteMany();
    // await prisma.entry.deleteMany();
    // await prisma.club.deleteMany();
    // await prisma.user.deleteMany();
    try {
        const user = await prisma.entry.findMany({
            include: {
                players: {
                    select: {
                        fn: true,
                        ln: true,
                    },
                },
            },
        });
        console.log(user);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
};

getPlayerdata();
```

This returns:

```
...
 {
    id: '22d94977-0159-48a9-b4fb-da120de3fcc7',
    season: 2023,
    league: 'EPL',
    pool: 'UK',
    userId: '16b9ab21-c28d-428e-85cb-05bbadc79cc6',
    goals: 0,
    own_goals: 0,
    net_goals: 0,
    suit: 'SPADES',
    createdAt: 2023-08-19T19:11:40.749Z,
    updatedAt: 2023-08-19T19:11:40.749Z,
    players: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
  }
...
]
```

I would like to have players names returned with that data: [{fn: "Mike" ln: "John}, {fn: "Abe" ln: "Lincoln}]

Answer (score 0):

The answer was that I didn't pay attention to the type of data structure that came back or really understand the default behavior of Prisma.

I'm getting back an array of objects and nested objects so I have to deal with that accordingly.

```html
 
        const entries = await prisma.entry.findMany({
            include: {
                user: {
                    select: {
                        fn: true,
                    },
                },
                players: {
                    select: {
                        fn: true,
                        ln: true,
                    },
                },
            },
        });

        entries.forEach((entry) => {
            console.log(entry.players);
        });
```

The output is now:

```html
[
  { fn: 'João Pedro', ln: 'Junqueira de Jesus' },
  { fn: 'Dominik', ln: 'Szoboszlai' },
  { fn: 'Joško', ln: 'Gvardiol' },
  { fn: 'Anthony', ln: 'Gordon' }
]
[
  { fn: 'Declan', ln: 'Rice' },
  { fn: 'James', ln: 'Tarkowski' },
  { fn: 'John', ln: 'Stones' },
  { fn: 'Brennan', ln: 'Johnson' }
]
[
  { fn: 'Dwight', ln: 'McNeil' },
  { fn: 'Bobby', ln: 'De Cordova-Reid' },
  { fn: 'João', ln: 'Palhinha Gonçalves' }
]
```